# how can i verify if a user and password paired exist in a hashtable?

Tags: java, methods, authentication, hashmap, class-method

im trying to create a shopping cart. rightnow i have issues with the login system. im trying to use a hashmap to keep the users with passwords and then trough another function verify if they exist paired. The problem is that the function has "non static method containsKey(Object)and i cant use verify_user method with the hmap. I would really appreciate some help. Thank you in advance :D!

```
package shoppingcart;

import java.util.HashMap;
import java.util.Scanner;

public class Shoppingcart {

public static void main(String[] args) {
  Scanner keyboard = new Scanner(System.in);
  /* This is how to declare HashMap */
  HashMap<String, String> hmap = new HashMap<>();
  /*Adding elements to HashMap*/
  hmap.put("Theyought47@einrot.com","a01652138");
  hmap.put("wcena201@ndfbmail.ga","6p4deq2gcl4k8bdc");
  hmap.put("0syed.sab@pokeett.site","7clqdwqnjz7ohj8e");
  hmap.put("oali.qasem@miur.ml","4trm8owbws7au24d");
  hmap.put("idigao.pga@888z5.ml","pqat88120ibwtya0");

  System.out.println("Ingresar usuario");
  String user = keyboard.nextLine();
  System.out.println("Ingresar Contraseña");
  String password = keyboard.nextLine();
  hmap.verify_user(user,password); //is this possible??
}

public static void verify_user(String user, String password){
    int counter = 0;
    int times = 0;
    while(counter < 3){
        boolean KeyFlag = HashMap.containsKey(user);//what does this error mean
        if(KeyFlag == true){
            boolean VFlag = HashMap.containsValue(password);
            if(VFlag = true){
                System.out.println("Acceso permitido, Bienvenido usuario " +user);
                counter = 3;
            }
            if(VFlag == false && times < 3){
                times ++;
                counter ++;
            }
            else{
                System.out.println("Acceso denagado, Cerrando el sistema");
                System.exit(0);
            }
        }
    }
}
}
```

Comment: Your code doesn't make sense anyway. There's no reason for the counter in `verify_user()`, and you need to check that (a) the user exists in the table and (b) *that* user has that password. Not merely both the user and the password exist separately.

Comment: If you wanted to check if a user and password pare exists in your hashmap then you can simply check `if(password.equals(hmap.get(user)))`.

Comment: @Gaurav thank yoy very much! it worked perfectly with this implementation :D Thanks for your help!

Answer (score 0):

Per [Javadoc on HashMap](https://docs.oracle.com/javase/8/docs/api/java/util/HashMap.html), you can do:

```
String user_password = hmap.get(user);
```

and check that the returned password is not null AND that the returned password is correct:

```
if(user_password == Null)
    System.out.println("User ID does not exist");

else if(user_password.equals(input_password))
    System.out.println("Correct user ID and password");

else
    System.out.println("Wrong password");
```

If the instance of the HashMap does not contain the user, the returned object will be Null. If it does exist, in your case, it will return a String that is the password for the user ID that you used as the key. Then all you would need to do is check that the given password matches the password for the user.

Comment: You would not normally distinguish between 'User ID does not exist' and 'wrong password'. That just tells the attacker when he's found a correct UserID and narrows his search space.

Comment: @EJP of course, but for the sake of concisely expressing what I am doing with the code, I'm printing out the facts.

Answer (score 0):

You can modify it like this:

```
 public static void main(String[] args) {
      Scanner keyboard = new Scanner(System.in);
      /* This is how to declare HashMap */
      HashMap<String, String> hmap = new HashMap<>();
      /*Adding elements to HashMap*/
      hmap.put("Theyought47@einrot.com","a01652138");
      hmap.put("wcena201@ndfbmail.ga","6p4deq2gcl4k8bdc");
      hmap.put("0syed.sab@pokeett.site","7clqdwqnjz7ohj8e");
      hmap.put("oali.qasem@miur.ml","4trm8owbws7au24d");
      hmap.put("idigao.pga@888z5.ml","pqat88120ibwtya0");

      System.out.println("Ingresar usuario");
      String user = keyboard.nextLine();
      System.out.println("Ingresar Contraseña");
      String password = keyboard.nextLine();
      verify_user(hmap,user,password); //is this possible??
    }

    public static void verify_user(HashMap<String,String> hash,String user, String password){
        int counter = 0;
        int times = 0;
        while(counter < 3){
            boolean KeyFlag = hash.containsKey(user);//what does this error mean
            if(KeyFlag == true){
                boolean VFlag = hash.containsValue(password);
                if(VFlag = true){
                    System.out.println("Acceso permitido, Bienvenido usuario " +user);
                    counter = 3;
                }
                if(VFlag == false && times < 3){
                    times ++;
                    counter ++;
                }
                else{
                    System.out.println("Acceso denagado, Cerrando el sistema");
                    System.exit(0);
                }
            }
        }
    }
```

The error means that to access the contains method you need an object of type HashMap as the method is non static and needs an object reference.